# OnCreateOptonsMenu called twice in Fragments with Drawer Menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I hava a mian activity with a navigation drawer, and a fragment page with some options menu.

then I put "setHasOptionsMenu(true)" in the fragments "onCreateView", and then override the "onCreateOptionsMenu" of the fragment.  But I found the behavior of the options menu is weird:

1. From the log I was told that the 'onCreateOptionsMenu' of the fragment was called, but some times the options just refuse to display.
2. If the options is there, then I pulled the drawer out, the title of the actionbar is changed to the app's name, but the options of the fragment is also there. By checking the log I found the the "onCreateOptionsMenu" is called twice, one after the drawer is open, the other after the drawer closed. The log:

> D/MainActivity﹕ onCreateOptionsMenu    <-- 1
>   D/DeviceFragment﹕onCreateOptionsMenu   <-- 2
>   D/DeviceFragment﹕ onCreateOptionsMenu  <-- 3

When the drawer open, '1' and '2' are called in order, when the drawer closed , '3' is called.

The relevant code segments:

MainActivity's onCreateOptionsMenu

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

DeviceFragments's onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.frag_device, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);


    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu");
}
```